# PHP MySQL Order list

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help?

My code is like this:

```
<ol><li>{$student_Value}</li> <ol>'
```

it gives result:

```
 1. Student101Name
 1. Student102Name
 1. Student103Name
```

I want something like:

> 1. Student101Name
> 2. Student102Name
> 3. Student103Name

Please help... Thank you!

Comment: Where is your MySQL query? You probably need to use "ORDER BY" clause.

Comment: It's hard to tell without more code. How does $student_Value get assigned?

Comment: How do actually get your current result?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `MySQL` to get the data you can add `ORDER BY` to the query to order the result!

[Here more info how to use ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

And change the HTML Code to be:

```
<ol>
    <li>$student_Value</li>
    <li>$student_Value</li>
    <li>$student_Value</li>
</ol>
```

PHP Code will be:

```
echo "<ol>";
echo "   <li> $student_Value </li> ";//write all student values like this
//more student values
echo "</ol>";
```

Comment: the $Student_value cannot be repeated or the student names repeat too... I am using actually PHPRunner and $Student_Value is an array

Answer (score 2):

Do not close the OL tag every time

OL = Ordered List

LI = List item

If you close and reopen the OL, it creates a new ordered list, and so restarting at 1.

```
<pre>

echo "&lt;ol&gt;";
foreach loop {
echo "&lt;li&gt;{$student_Value}&lt;/li&gt;";
}
echo "&lt;/ol&gt;";

</pre>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is more CSS related than PHP or SQL.

The reason is probably that your output is:

```
<ol><li>$student_Value</li></ol>
<ol><li>$student_Value</li></ol>
<ol><li>$student_Value</li></ol>
```

Each student should be a list item within the ordered list:

```
<?php

print "<ol>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    print "<li>{$row['student']}</li>";
}

print "</ol>";

?>
```

Comment: This duplicate the Student Value

Comment: The example was only meant to explain the structure. Since you have not included the code that fetches the result, I thought this answer would be fulfilling enough. I'll update the answer to try and make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like that

```
<ol>
<?php
   for($i=0; $i<count($studentValue); $i++)
   {
?>
      <li><?php echo $studentValue[$i]; ?></li>
<?php 
   }
?>
<ol>
```

I am giving you above example to tell you that under a 'ol' tag 'li' must be multiple to get your require result.

Comment: Sorry it still returns the same:

Comment: It all returns the same thing... Is there a way to number the row instead of $Student_value?

Comment: I have tested it and it's returns that you need.

Comment: $studentValue=array('student1','student12','student123');
put the above line just before of for loop and see the result..